# Maximum length exceeded in SSRS Report Model

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I was working with Report Models, at the time of deployment an exception occurred:

> error 101
>
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: maximum request length
>   exceeded.

I got rid of this error by adding attribute `maxRequestLength` in the element `httpRuntime`, but if sometimes the file size exceeds again, I have to change the value given to `maxRequestLength`.

Is there any permanent resolution for this. Shall I do anything dynamically?

Thanks in advance